# Windows XP client wont authenticate to Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp

First our environment. We have a Windows Server 2003 machine providing all services for Windows, and a pfSense 2.4 firewall providing other services such as DHCP and DNS. The firewall does not directly provide dynamic DNS registration. We have recently changed the DNS IP address, and the DHCP server puts out the DC IP address as a WINS server.

We had a power outage and the client rebooted. The server had a full system disk as well. When that happened, this user on Windows XP could no longer log in to the network shares that they need access to.

The user was recreated on server side, but still cannot log in. Also had user change password on local machine, and reboot. No change. On the local machine it says either the name or password is wrong.

Logging in from another Windows XP machine says that it could not reach the DC for the OFFICE domain (or OFFICE.LOCAL I am assuming). I can log into that machine fine but it has my username as a local user.

Logging in as that user on MacOS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) works fine.

Another heavy Windows network user is using MacOS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and has reported no problems with network shares (although printing is another matter, but that is - I *think!* - not relevant here).

I'm no Windows wizard, so here I am asking you wizards out there. What gives? Do I need to upgrade this person to a newer Windows?

One thing that is continually coming up is that the DC can't be found because the DNS lookup failed - or the registration failed. Do I need to add our server.office.local to the (non-dynamic) DNS?

Comment: Since XP went end of life, they should have already been upgraded, months if not years ago. And 2003 will be EOL next year, so you should already have migration plans in place for it.

Comment: You should have upgraded off both of those platforms about 5 years ago.  Forget troubleshooting that ancient pile of crap... install a new environment with modern OSes, and save yourself a lot of pointless trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the issue lies with the workstation and not the users account.

With that said :

1. Ensure the DNS servers are correct on the clients workstation
2. Remove the workstation from the domain and then re-add it. To do this right click on my computer, select **Properties**. From there click on the **Computer Name** tab and click **Change**. Remove everything from the **Domain** portion and add the text WORKGROUP into the **Workgroup** section then save and reboot. When the computer boots up again go back into the **Computer Name** area and then remove the WORKGROUP text from  the **Workgroup** text field and then add your domain in the **Domain** text field.
3. If that fails ensure that the workstation has the appropriate ability to connect to the domain controller (You can verify with telnet commands)

   telnet server.domainname.com 389

The above command will see if your computer is able to communicate with the server *server.domainname.com* on TCP port 389 (Standard LDAP port). Note that you may be running LDAP on another port such as 636 if it's SSL LDAP

Comment: How do I perform #2 and #3?

Comment: @Mei edited answer for clarity.

Comment: When attempting to rejoin the domain, we get an error on the client about not being able to find the SRV record associated with *_ldap._tcp.dc_msdcs.office.local*

Comment: Changing the DNS from the local firewall (with all servers in it) to the Windows DC DNS worked wonders - but now some of the user's shortcuts to Shares seem to be bad, but at least he can now access things. He is our only Windows user that logs into the network normally. (The rest either don't use Windows to log in or don't log into the network at all.)

Comment: Create a zone on the Windows DC for the shares and create new A records that correspond to the servers that the shares are hosted on. That should resolve your problem.